# Ios build release build issue flutter App

Tags: flutter, release-builds, flutter-ios

Flutter app when installing the iOS app in simulator from Xcode it works good, it is not working in the build which I distributed the iOS app using ADHOC mode it is not working properly and the ui for some screens is not loaded properly, Is there any way to fix this build issue. Thanks